# Fetching a single row from a db based on id results in error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I wish to fetch a single row from a sqlite db.

I use the following code to fetch values.

```
public ShipmentStatusDao getShipmentStatusRow(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SHIPMENTSTATUS, new String[]{KEY_NOTES,
                        KEY_PHOTOS, KEY_DOCUMENTS}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        ShipmentStatusDao notification = new ShipmentStatusDao(cursor.getInt(0),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

        return notification;
    }
```

Im using the following code to invoke the above method,

```
 ShipmentStatusDao shipmentStatusRow = db.getShipmentStatusRow(1);
 shipmentStatusRow.getDate();
```

Im getting the following error,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.
>                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
>                                                          at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>                                                          at com.vaighai.handlers.NotificationDbHandler.getShipmentStatusRow(NotificationDbHandler.java:364)
>                                                          at com.vaighai.fragments.StatusFragment$5.onItemClick(StatusFragment.java:237)
>                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
>                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
>                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3339)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-16 14:54:32.826
>   2337-7411/? I/ActivityManager: Notify an ApplicationCrash

How can I be able to rectify the above error?

Comment: `if (cursor != null){//your code }` change like this will help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only check if your `Cursor` is null but you do not check if it's empty

`moveToFirst()` returns a `boolean` so you know it is empty or not. You can change this

```
if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

ShipmentStatusDao notification = new ShipmentStatusDao(cursor.getInt(0),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

return notification;
```

Into this

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    ShipmentStatusDao notification = new ShipmentStatusDao(cursor.getInt(0),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

    cursor.close(); // Don't forget to close BTW
    return notification;
}  else {
    // Cursor is null or empty, you need to do something with this
    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Also, you have only three columns in your selection by supplying `new String[]{KEY_NOTES, KEY_PHOTOS, KEY_DOCUMENTS}` in your query. If you would change that into `null`, the `Cursor` contains all columns. This should solve your error

Comment: i tried it but the same error is being thrown again

Comment: That's because you are selecting columns. Updated my answer

Comment: that works but it prints something like com.model.ShipmentStatusDao@429cdda0

Answer (score 2):

You are querying only three fields(KEY_NOTES,
                        KEY_PHOTOS, KEY_DOCUMENTS). So cursor.getString(3) will throw error.

Answer (score -1):

All cursor related code/ queries should come in one block of code.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SHIPMENTSTATUS, new String[]{KEY_NOTES,
                        KEY_PHOTOS, KEY_DOCUMENTS}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) { 
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ... // simply do this 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !